# How to make an element to take another element height

Tags: jquery, resize

I have created 2 responsive boxes, first box have a picture inside and the other one some text.
Both have a width: 50%; and first box height: 100%. However.. whenever I resize the window, I want the box number 2 height to be the same with the one from box number 1.

I have created this jquery and it works, but it doesn't work when I resize the window. I think a solution to this may be for the jquery to be executed whenever I resize the window, but I don't have any idea how. This is what I have done:

```
<script>
var Box = $('.theElement');
$('.theElement2').css({ height: Box.height() });
</script>
```

Thank you for the advice! The final solution looks like this:

```
var Box = $('.theElement');

$(window).load(function() {
$('.theElement2').css({ height: Box.height() });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
$('.theElement2').css({ height: Box.height() });
}).resize();
```

Note: I had to introduce the load function because when I refreshed the page the jquery sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var Box = $('.theElement');
    $('.theElement2').css({ height: Box.height() });
}).resize();
```

Comment: Thank you, but now it's working only when I resize. If I refresh the page without resizing the window the jquery doesn't work.. I have to resize the window in order to be executed.

Comment: @RussuGeorge -- Edited and fixed. Add `.resize()` to the end of the event to auto trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to wrap the setting of the height in a function, and then call it upon DOM ready as well as upon the window resize event:

```
$(function() {
    var setHeight = function() {
        var Box = $('.theElement');
        $('.theElement2').css({ height: Box.height() });
    });

    // Run on DOM ready
    setHeight();

    // Run on window resize
    $(window).resize(setHeight);
});
```

Some optimisation hindsight: you might want to consider throttling the `resize` event, if many calculations are being performed at the same time. Browsers often fire the event too frequently ;)